# Intellij Abnormal build process termination (Error connecting to 127.0.0.1)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have installed IntelliJ IDEA CE and jdk 1.8.0_152 on my mac OS Sierra version10.12.6 and written a simple hello world program. When i try to build the project through the UI (CMD+F9), it gives me the following error:

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination:
Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jarSLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementationSLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:50569; reason: nulljava.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.ensureOpen(...)(Unknown Source)
Exiting.
```

I have disabled the firewall. I am struggling to get a simple program to work with IntelliJ. I have tried re-installing IntelliJ and restarting my mac already.

```
IntelliJ configuration:
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.6
Build #IC-172.4574.11, built on November 13, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b12 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a more recent JDK build for your project. jdk1.8.0_152 is quite old. The issue can be also caused by the antivirus/firewall killing the process or blocking the connections.